# posting on facebook newsfeed is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

i am running hackbook sample for iphone using facebook sdk but when i try to publish on my newsfeed it is posting on my timeline but it is not showing in my newsfeed . i tried another example from  this [facebook example](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/) link but it is also posting on my timeline but not in my newsfeed.the code for publishing using hackbook sample is

```
 - (void)apiDialogFeedUser 
 {
     currentAPICall = kDialogFeedUser;
     SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

     // The action links to be shown with the post in the feed
     NSArray* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       @"Get Started",@"name",@"http://m.facebook.com/apps/hackbookios/",@"link", nil], nil];
     NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
     // Dialog parameters
     NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"I'm using the Hackbook for iOS app", @"name",
                               @"Hackbook for iOS.", @"caption",
                               @"Check out Hackbook for iOS to learn how you can make your iOS apps social using Facebook Platform.", @"description",
                               @"http://m.facebook.com/apps/hackbookios/", @"link",
                               @"http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png", @"picture",
                               actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                               nil];

     HackbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HackbookAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}
```

anybody else has face this type of issue
any suggestions will be great help

Comment: a new issue came i created new facebook account and added to my old account friend list then whatever i posted from my app its is showing in the new account newsfeed properly but not in my newsfeed

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OFFICIAl iOS dev tutorial made by Facebook themselves:

[iOS Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

Comment: i tried that example but the problem is still there and another issue came i created new facebook account and added to my old account friend list then whatever i posted from my app its is showing in the new account newsfeed properly but not in my newsfeed